Why does validation error occur even when requirements are filled
I'm trying to do login with blazor, but now the problem is that whenever I type in the data into inputtext fields I get validation error "this field is required" eventhough the information is entered. The model looks like this
 public class UserModel
 {
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname is required")]
     public string Surname { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
     [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email format")]
     public string Email { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
     [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 6 characters long")]
     public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
 }

I doubt that this part is the problem, but dataAccess file that should contact database and insert data looks like this
    public async Task<int> RegisterUser(UserModel user, string connectionString)
    {
        user.PasswordHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(user.PasswordHash);

        string sql = @"
    INSERT INTO Users (Name, Surname, Email, PasswordHash) 
    VALUES (@Name, @Surname, @Email, @PasswordHash);
";

        using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            return await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, user);
        }
    }

and the form which I try to insert data into looks like this
<EditForm EditContext="@editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleRegister" FormName="registerForm">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText @bind-Value="userModel.Name" Placeholder="Name" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="userModel.Surname" Placeholder="Surname" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="userModel.Email" Placeholder="Email" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="userModel.PasswordHash" Placeholder="Password" type="password" />


    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</EditForm>

The problem is like I said, whenever I try to submit input data, I  get the verification error message, even if required data is inserted.

Here's a Minimal Reproducible Example based on the code you've provided.  It's the home page from a Blazor Server / Global Interactivity project.
It works as it should, so you can't be showing us all your code.
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm EditContext="@editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleRegister">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText class="form-control mb-2" @bind-Value="userModel.Name" Placeholder="Name" />
    <InputText class="form-control mb-2" @bind-Value="userModel.Surname" Placeholder="Surname" />
    <InputText class="form-control mb-2" @bind-Value="userModel.Email" Placeholder="Email" />
    <InputText class="form-control mb-2" @bind-Value="userModel.PasswordHash" Placeholder="Password" type="password" />

    <div class="text-end">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private UserModel userModel = new();
    private EditContext? editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new(userModel);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void HandleRegister()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Register");
    }

    public class UserModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname is required")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email format")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 6 characters long")]
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    }

}


